# Find index of first Char(Letter) in string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a mental block and can't seem to figure this out, sure its pretty easy 0_o

I have the following string: "5555S1"

String can contain any number of digits, followed by a Letter(A-Z), followed by numbers again.
How do I get the index of the Letter(S), so that I can substring so get everything following the Letter

Ie: 5555S1
Should return S1

Cheers

Comment: A good starting point would be to read this: http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also check if the integer representation of the character is >= 65 && <=90.

Simple Python:

```
test = '5555Z187456764587368457638'

for i in range(0,len(test)):
    if test[i].isalpha():
            break

print test[i:]
```

Yields: Z187456764587368457638

Comment: Although this wasn't in C#, the logic pushed me into the right direction so manage to write a function in C# that does what I Need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didn't say what language your using I'm going to pick the one I want to answer in - c#

`String.Index` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx for more

for good measure here it is in [java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) `string.indexOf`

Comment: Not sure how you think String.Index will work? With String.Index you need to provide the char you looking for, in my case it can be any alphabetic letter. How would you accomplish this with String.Index?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to loop through the string untill you find a letter.

while(! isAlpha(s[i])
    i++;
or something should work.

Comment: Python also has isdigit() and isalpha() methods,, if you're using that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but it does solve your problem.
(Although you can use it to work out the index)

Your problem is a good candidate for Regular Expressions (regex)

Here is one I prepared earlier:

```
    String code = "1234A0987";

    //timeout optional but needed for security (so bad guys dont overload your server)
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150);


   //Magic here:
   //Pattern == (Block of 1 or more numbers)(block of 1 or more not numbers)(Block of 1 or more numbers)                      
    String regexPattern = @"^(?<firstNum>\d+)(?<notNumber>\D+)(?<SecondNum>\d+)?";
    Regex r = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.None, timeout);

    Match m = r.Match(code);
    if (m.Success)//We got a match!
    {     
        Console.WriteLine ("SecondNumber: {0}",r.Match(code).Result("${SecondNum}"));
        Console.WriteLine("All data (formatted): {0}",r.Match(code).Result("${firstNum}-${notNumber}-${SecondNum}")); 

        Console.WriteLine("Offset length (not that you need it now): {0}", r.Match(code).Result("${firstNum}").Length); 

    }
```

Output:

```
SecondNumber: 0987 
All data (formatted): 1234-A-0987 
Offset length (not that you need it now): 4
```

Further info on this example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ew9az0.aspx).

So there you go you can even work out what that index was.

[Regex cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)